# trying to get a count of records(records more than 50000 in object) in one object through apex class

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

Trying to get a count of records(records more than 50000 in object) in one object through apex class(Getting limit Exception). Looking for any alternate solution.

I used database.countQuery()statement, but still I am getting records limit exception.

Any one give me alternate solution to get records count.

My query is dynamic query like:

```
String s = 'Case';
String soql = 'SELECT COUNT() FROM' + s;
Integer cnt = Database.countQuery(soql);
```

Comment: What was your query? In the developer console I just ran `select count(id) from Lead` in the query editor and it returned 433316.

Comment: My query is dynamic query like String s = 'case'; String soql='select count() from'+s '; Integer cnt=database.countQuery(soql); This is all my code.

Comment: Requirement like this. I want to list out object name and count of its corresponding records in object, that's why i iterating loop with object names and executing dynamic query inside the loop for all objects.

Comment: Have you checked out the storage usage section in setup?  It lists out the number of records for each object.

Comment: Yes I did checked storage usage, in that one custom object has 130000 records it is showing. Can we access storage usage data in to apex class? I checked storage usage accessibility in schema level but did't get any reference to access in apex class.

Answer (score 6):

Why shouldn't you use `database.query(query)` instead.

```
AggregateResult results = database.query('SELECT COUNT(id) result FROM someSObject');

System.debug('No of ids are: '+results.get('result')); // Id are always unique
```

Using `database.countQuery()` or `[SELECT count() FROM someObject];` hits governor limit if records > 50000

If you can use @[readonly](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.) in you class then that limit will extend to million.

Also try to filter it with some criteria using `WHERE` clause, field which have no significant of counting if they have some particular value that doesn't matter.

Comment: does the code you highlighted works if number of records returned are more than 50000 ? will the below work for more than 50000 rows : AggregateResult results = database.query('SELECT COUNT(id) result FROM someSObject');
System.debug('No of ids are: '+results.get('result')); // Id are always unique

Comment: @Walker for records > 50000 it won't work. You can use @ readonly attribute on page to extend this limit.

Comment: i need to use such queries in a class which implements Batchable. this batch class will be scheduled to run at specific intervals. Is there any relaxation in terms of number of records returned in case SOQL is being called in batch context ?

Answer (score -4):

creat a list for the records li
and count them as count = li.size();
take one outputField in visualfroce page.

try this

Comment: Could you please add more useful information? Your answer is very unclear at the moment. Thanks.